# Is the Hubbard 2-body potential non diagonal in both direct and momentum space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, hamiltonian, second-quantization, tight-binding

I was looking at the following table from these lecture notes:
http://www.lassp.cornell.edu/clh/Book-sample/1.1.pdf

[image]

And was wondering if the 2-body potential is always non-diagonal, or if there is a space in which it could be diagonal.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? It would be diagonal in its eigenbasis space by definition.

Comment: And which one would that be? I just want to make sure it is not diagonal in neither direct nor Fourier space.

Comment: Do they look diagonal if you plug in expressions for the density operators?

Comment: Note that the Hubbard model typically uses an on-site interaction (like $U(r)=\delta(r)$), in which case the two-body potential is diagonal in real space.

Answer (score 0):

The momentum representation is diagonal. Since the density $\rho(\mathbf{x})$ is a real quantity, it's Fourier transform obeys $\tilde\rho(-\mathbf{k}) =\tilde\rho(\mathbf{k})^*$. Therefore the momentum space term can be written $\sum_k \tilde{U}(k) |\tilde{\rho}(k)|^2$, which is diagonal.

Of course as alluded to in the comments above, the question of whether there exists a basis where an operator is diagonal is equivalent to asking whether the eigenvectors form a complete basis. For any self-adjoint operator [this is indeed the case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-adjoint_operator#Spectral_theorem).